# Do remote employees need permission to move to another state?

Tags: telecommute, relocation

I work in a state and my employer is in another state. I would like to move with my family to another state that is actually closer to the headquarters. Do I have to get permission from my employer since I am remote and could they fire me if they find out I moved?

Comment: I think the wording here is a bit awkward. Perhaps a variation on "Could I lose my job?" would be better than "Do I need permission?". Working adults don't need a note from the teacher and aren't indentured servants.

Comment: But it's a legal and company-specific question, as @Lilienthal pointed out below - if you'd be the first employee working in that state, it would mean that your company would now be required to adhere to that state's tax and employment-related laws, and whether they're willing to do that is a question for them and their legal team. If they already have employees there, the calculation is very different. There's no one-size-fits-all answer besides "ask your company and see what they say".

Comment: The one-size-fits-all answer is that the employer ***will absolutely*** have to undertake some administrative work as relates to not only state employment taxes, *but also* health insurance, worker's compensation insurance, and unemployment insurance, and adherence to any regulatory policies in the new state.  Even if the insurers handle employees in the old state and the new, the employer is required to communicate the change in locale so the insurers do not incur foreseeable risks.

Comment: "But it's a legal and company-specific question"  Not in the slightest.  The OP does not have a clue whether **legal, or other - or whatever - issues are involved**.  indeed note Adam that your comment (ie, your comment right here) provides a fantastic amount of information about the question at hand.,

Comment: hi @XavierJ on the other hand, a vast amount of contract work in the US now is "W2" (or whatever the terminology is): the employer couldn't give a stuff about what you are or where you live, every single aspect of tax and healthcare etc, **is on you**: so, your comment is completely wrong (or, wrong half the time).  indeed, that's **more** information that should be pointed out in answer to this actual question.

Comment: @Fattie the employer's requirement to pay state unemployment insurance and Workers Compensation Insurance is not negated by the employee's location. These factors apply to all W-2 employees - even those working from home, "contract" or otherwise.

Comment: Sorry I meant ***NOT W2*** of course - I can't edit it any longer.  1099 employees in the US simply have a check mailed to them, and that's it, the company need do nothing else whatsoever, except maybe give them a 1099-MISC for convenience.

Comment: @Fattie - "The OP does not have a clue whether legal, or other - or whatever - issues are involved." That's why the right answer is "ask your company" (and because the response will vary wildly from company to company, the question should be closed). If the company says "we're not going to deal with employees in [new state], so if you move there we'll accept your resignation", there's nothing we can tell the OP to help.

Comment: @Fattie - if the OP is a contractor, not an employee, then the question needs to be reworded to say "client" instead of "employer", and in such cases, they'd still likely need to talk to an employment lawyer in the new state to ensure they're doing everything necessary under the new jurisdiction (as well as letting the company know in case the company has its own restrictions against hiring contractors in the new state).

Comment: hi @AdamV - sure, you should tell the OP that.  (I disagree with you BTW, it's completely commonplace to describe your contractor-paperwork employer, as your "employer".)

Comment: @Fattie - "it's completely commonplace to describe your contractor-paperwork employer, as your "employer"" - in the context of "asking questions on SE", I disagree. The answers will be different if you're an employee vs a contractor (at least in the US), so it's important to be specific.

Comment: @AdamV  - sure, the OP should clarify that.  it seems to be a TDU (transient disappearing user) so it's all irrelevant anyway, really

Comment: Also, consider your pay scale. Your pay may be recalculated if you move to a place that has a cheaper cost of living.

Answer (score 13):

> Do I have to get permission from my employer since I am remote and
>   could they fire me if they find out I moved?

Assuming you are in the US, you never need permission to move. But you should inform your employer of your plan to move, and the anticipated move date.

At a minimum, they will need to update their records for tax purposes, employee mailings, telephone access, etc. It's also possible they will want you to change your connection methods while working from a different remote location (I'm imagining using a different VPN, for example).

If you worked at the office and moved, they wouldn't fire you (assuming you still came into the same office each day). I see no reason to suspect they would fire you for moving while working remotely.

Comment: "*I see no reason to suspect they would fire you for moving while working remotely.*" There's actually a pretty major one: tax and legal requirements. Someone working in a state is covered by that state's employment laws. That alone could involve higher expenses or a greater burden for the employer, but it also means a hell of a lot of administrative overhead if the company doesn't already employ people in that state. That doesn't impact the OP in this case but many employers will opt to sever the relationship in such a situation.

Comment: Some states have rather ominous rules about business entities, something that is needed to have an employee in that state.  My employer balked at my move because of that.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere It shouldn't matter but from a fiscal and legal perspective there are [important consequences](http://www.askamanager.org/2016/04/why-its-complicated-for-your-employer-to-let-you-work-from-another-state.html) to moving to a state that your employer isn't already active in. There is in my view a very real chance that the employer would decide that it's not a workable arrangement and at that point moving constitutes resigning. And it's not just the usual "bad employers might fire you" caveat here. It's reasonable for an employer to simply say they won't take on that burden.

Comment: A lot of people are commenting about tax and legal issues, but I'm curious about something on that front.   If, for example, my office is in Memphis, TN, but I lived 10 miles away in West Memphis, AR, and I drive across the state line every day to work.  Wouldn't that all fall under the Tennessee laws, taxes (none), etc?   How is this different than the poster's situation where his official office is still in the same state?   Does it really matter when you physically do the work or where your official office is?   I don't know the answer to that, I'm just curious.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Interesting.   I used those cities because they were the first I thought of that crossed a state line, it doesn't matter where.  I never knew that.   I have worked places where we had people who lived in other states and did all their work via a remote connection to our computers.  They were officially part of our office, even had a desk, just never there.   I guess I never thought about it from this standpoint, thanks for the knowledge.

Comment: @bluegreen - I believe (though I'm not certain) the test is "where do you do your work". If you're doing your work in Tennessee, you're subject to Tennessee laws. If you're working remotely, you're subject to the laws of your home state.

Comment: Are not most of these issues something the employee themselfs have to worry about?  The employee themselfs will have to worry about turning the correct forms into the state, to document their income, in order to eventually pay their income taxes for the year.  Unless we are talking about a company doing everything by hand (surrounding tax withholding), I don't see how a remote worker changing locations, could possible effect them

Comment: At my previous (large, multi-state) company with remote employees, a coworker who had to move for family reasons was told that he could not remain employed in his new location because the company had no presence there and the state requirements were onerous.  (Illinois, in case you're wondering.)  Unfortunately this does happen.  We lost an excellent developer. :-(

Comment: @bluegreen a bit of both.  Mostly it'd be TN law since that's where you're working.  But your employer would need to do AR taxes for you.  OTOH if your employer is <10mi from the state line and has more than a handful of employees, you're probably not the only person who's doing similar so supporting 2 states worth of taxes is a sunk cost already.

Answer (score 8):

You need to inform them as it affects your tax situation-  they need to withhold taxes for the state you're working for.  But it shouldn't be an issue, remote from one place is the same as remote from another.

Answer (score 4):

**I just realized something!**

As a matter of fact, in the US a few companies that have remote workers, can only hire them in certain states.  This is somewhat commonplace, the jobs ads even will say "can hire remotely in .. list of states".

{Note that there's no fundamental legal or tax reason preventing any state - but due to the I assume accounting and perhaps healthcare corporate structure preferred/used by the company, they can only hire in certain states.}

So, indeed, it's pretty unlikely this is the case, but really you should just straight away ask someone about your coming move.

---

There's no hard and fast rule.

I'd say "you should tell them" and "they should accept that".

Note that: they can fire you, for any reason, at all - or for no reason - at any time they want.  I assume you're in the USA; almost all employment is just "at will".

(Just as you can leave, if you happen to want to.)

So **yes** quite simply, in a sense, "they can fire you because you moved".

Say: you moved, and for some reason you didn't tell them, and when you moved it caused a lot of chaos causing you to miss things at work, and additionally your time zone changed (and you didn't tell them that), and generally your moving caused problems (for some reason or another).

Sure, they could fire you.

Note that, if you worked **at the office** (and lived in the same city), and you happened to be moving house: it would be a bit weird to *not tell them that*.  You'd mention it to your boss, you know?  Moving is a big disturbance, and they'd appreciate knowing.

I'd say that a general point: when you work remotely, it's a *really good perk*. IME, most "remote employers" don't want any messing around you know?  Remote employees sort of have to be "more tight" than old-fashioned on-site employees.

As with any work issue, if you're an *absolutely stellar* team member, you can get away with anything.

Again in short,

1 - "you should tell them"

2 - "they should accept that".

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It makes sense. Let's hope it makes sense to them as well.

Comment: The bottom line is you **do need to tell them**.  Tell them as early as possible.  What I'd do is this, say to your boss "Say, we're thinking of moving, actually to XYZ. Who would I tell at the company to update my tax records - would it be Jack in Accounting?"  Then you'll be all set.

Comment: "There's no hard and fast rule." - I'm not sure about that given different states have different employment laws and, of course, different tax rates etc. For example, California has different laws concerning overtime and paid time off compared to Connecticut.

Comment: quite right, the whole tax/accounting situation does matter!

Comment: This answer could use some edit work. The rambling nature of your prose and lack of structure makes it hard to read and you're kind of burying the answer.

Comment: Hi @Lilienthal, welcome to SO.  Do not hesitate to click "edit" and improve this (or any) answer in any way.  Good thinking.  Looking forward to your work.

Comment: @Fattie Thanks, but as you might tell from the diamond next to my name I've been here a while. :) I only wanted to give you some advice on how to improve your answer, it's entirely your prerogative whether you agree or not and whether you wanted to edit your question or leave it as is.

Comment: It looks like the telling my employer did not work. Although we have another employee in the state I needed to move to they denied me. Something about they don't have clients there. They denial seems very personal.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the whole stream there is one point that no one touched on. An employer can agree to the relocation but they may reduce your compensation if you are moving to a location with a lower cost of living. With the assumption that they would/could hire someone to do what you do at a much lower level of compensation. I have heard as much as 25%

Comment: In the US, I don't think you can get away with reducing salary because a remote employee moves to a location that has a perceived lower cost of living....